# Position an hr tag to look more natural

Tags: html, css

This line break I added doesn't sit where I want it to be. I want to center it between the Header and Images below.

I tried margin-bottom: 20px; but it pushed the images down the page which I don't want. I just want to keep the dimensions and center it between.

The CSS you are most likely looking for is at the bottom of the css page.

```css
/* PROCESS **********/

#process {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#process-span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#process img {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10%;
  -moz-border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px 1px;
}

#process p {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 235px;
  color: white;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#process h4 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#process .btn-go {
  margin-bottom: 500px;
  background-color: #4AA0D5;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px white solid;
}

#process .btn-go:hover,
#process .btn-go:focus {
  color: #4AA0D5;
  border: 2px #4AA0D5 solid !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0%;
  -moz-border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#process .bottom-line {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="process">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>How the Process Works</h2>
    <div class="lead2">
      <hr class="bottom-line">
    </div>
    <!-- lead2 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="img/image2.png" alt="Design">
        <span><p>Reach out to me and describe the type of project you want &amp; audience its for.</p></span>
      </div>
      <!-- col -->
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="img/image1.png" alt="Relax">
        <p>Sit back and relax! Watch your project grow with routine progress reports &amp; quick-to-respond communication.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- col -->
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="img/image3.png" alt="Finish">
        <p>The project will be turned into you at the agreed time and considered completed only when you are
          <bold>100%</bold> satisfied.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- col -->

    </div>
    <!-- row -->

  </div>
  <!-- container -->
  <h4><a href="#contact" class="btn-go">Let's Do It!</a></h4>
</section>
<!-- project-features -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin: 1rem auto 1.5rem;` to the `hr` as in the snippet below. The different top/bottom distances come from the fact that the header above it has more default padding-bottom than the element that follows has padding-top.

```css
/* PROCESS **********/

.lead2 hr {
  margin: 1rem auto 1.5rem;
}

#process {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#process-span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#process img {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10%;
  -moz-border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px 1px;
}

#process p {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 235px;
  color: white;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#process h4 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#process .btn-go {
  margin-bottom: 500px;
  background-color: #4AA0D5;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px white solid;
}

#process .btn-go:hover,
#process .btn-go:focus {
  color: #4AA0D5;
  border: 2px #4AA0D5 solid !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0%;
  -moz-border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#process .bottom-line {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <body>
    <section id="process">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>How the Process Works</h2>
        <div class="lead2">
          <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>
        <!-- lead2 -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/image2.png" alt="Design">
            <span><p>Reach out to me and describe the type of project you want &amp; audience its for.</p></span>
          </div>
          <!-- col -->
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/image1.png" alt="Relax">
            <p>Sit back and relax! Watch your project grow with routine progress reports &amp; quick-to-respond communication.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- col -->
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/image3.png" alt="Finish">
            <p>The project will be turned into you at the agreed time and considered completed only when you are
              <bold>100%</bold> satisfied.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- col -->

        </div>
        <!-- row -->

      </div>
      <!-- container -->
      <h4><a href="#contact" class="btn-go">Let's Do It!</a></h4>
    </section>
    <!-- project-features -->
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways you can do this. You aren't using any sort of reset or anything, so the default margins on the `h2` and `hr` are coming from the browser and that will vary from browser to browser. If you want there to be an equal space between the `h2`, `hr`, and image section, I would remove the margins from the `h2` and add a consistent top/bottom margin on the `hr`, and you can use whatever margin value you want there.

```css
/* PROCESS **********/

#process {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#process-span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#process img {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10%;
  -moz-border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 1px 1px;
}

#process p {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 235px;
  color: white;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#process h4 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#process .btn-go {
  margin-bottom: 500px;
  background-color: #4AA0D5;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px white solid;
}

#process .btn-go:hover,
#process .btn-go:focus {
  color: #4AA0D5;
  border: 2px #4AA0D5 solid !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0%;
  -moz-border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#process .bottom-line {
  width: 50px;
}

#process h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#process hr {
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <body>
    <section id="process">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>How the Process Works</h2>
        <div class="lead2">
          <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>
        <!-- lead2 -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/image2.png" alt="Design">
            <span><p>Reach out to me and describe the type of project you want &amp; audience its for.</p></span>
          </div>
          <!-- col -->
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/image1.png" alt="Relax">
            <p>Sit back and relax! Watch your project grow with routine progress reports &amp; quick-to-respond communication.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- col -->
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="img/image3.png" alt="Finish">
            <p>The project will be turned into you at the agreed time and considered completed only when you are
              <bold>100%</bold> satisfied.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- col -->

        </div>
        <!-- row -->

      </div>
      <!-- container -->
      <h4><a href="#contact" class="btn-go">Let's Do It!</a></h4>
    </section>
    <!-- project-features -->
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```